# Accounting for auto correlation in 2-level nested effects

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, autocorrelation

I'm attempting to account for autocorrelation within my 2-level nested mixed-effects model within nlme:

An example of the data I'm working with is:

```
I   G   P   T   DV  value
1   1   1   1   DV1 5.0685
2   1   1   2   DV1 4.7346
3   1   1   3   DV1 5.871
4   1   2   1   DV1 4.1047
5   1   2   2   DV1 4.4137
6   1   2   3   DV1 2.5056
7   1   3   1   DV1 2.2534
8   1   3   2   DV1 1.2088
9   1   3   3   DV1 6.9312
10  1   4   1   DV1 6.7197
11  1   4   2   DV1 4.1462
12  1   4   3   DV1 2.8413
13  1   5   1   DV1 5.2931
14  1   5   2   DV1 6.3865
15  1   5   3   DV1 2.8906
16  2   6   1   DV1 1.8438
17  2   6   2   DV1 3.3494
18  2   6   3   DV1 3.9079
19  2   7   1   DV1 2.6242
20  2   7   2   DV1 3.0441
21  2   7   3   DV1 5.8332
22  2   8   1   DV1 1.016
23  2   8   2   DV1 3.0086
24  2   8   3   DV1 5.1122


where:
I = Index
G = Group
P = Participant
T = Time
DV = three DV's in long-form
value = value of DV for the participant at said time

DV: factor dummy code for the multivariate data
Time: factor representing the three intervention points: pre, post, post
```

The model fit is:

```
model <- lme(value ~ variable:Time + 0 ,  data = na.omit(Data), random =~  1 | Group/Participant, 
             control = lmeControl(maxIter = 2000, msMaxIter = 2009, niterEM = 50,
                msMaxEval = 4000))
```

When I attempt to add autocorrelation to my model via:

```
correlation = corAR1(form = ~ as.numeric(Time) | Group/Participant)

model <- lme(value ~ variable:Time + 0 ,  data = na.omit(Data), random =~  1 | Group/Participant, correlation = corAR1(form = ~ as.numeric(Time) | Group/Participant), 
             control = lmeControl(maxIter = 2000, msMaxIter = 2009, niterEM = 50,
                msMaxEval = 4000))
```

I get the following error:

```
covariate must have unique values within groups for "corAR1" objects
```

The only way I can get the model to work is via setting the `corAR1(form = ~1 | Group/Participant)`:

```
model <- lme(value ~ variable:Time + 0 ,  data = na.omit(Data), random =~  1 | Group/Participant, correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | Group/Participant), 
             control = lmeControl(maxIter = 2000, msMaxIter = 2009, niterEM = 50,
                msMaxEval = 4000))
```

at which point I get a phi coefficient

Is this approach correct?

**Edit 1**: I figured out that the reason that I'm getting this error is that this is a multivariate analysis in the long-form. Essentially, since the DV repeats the data, so do all the participants and groups. Which means that time 1, participant 1, in group 1 will appear 3 times in the data.

To account for this, I added:

```
correlation = corAR1(form = ~ variable:as.numeric(Time) | Group/Participant)
```

However, I now get the following warnings:

```
In variable:as.numeric(Time) :
  numerical expression has 9 elements: only the first used
```

I have no clue why I get these now. Any ideas?

Other than the errors, my first approach:

```
correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | Group/Participant)
```

and

```
correlation = coarAR1(form = ~ variable:as.numeric(Time) | Group/Participant)
```

yield the same results in terms of both the phi correlation coefficient and the correlation matrix of fixed effects